# My meter is showing code FU6-04 what does this mean?

Tags: electrical, meter

There was storm last night ! The power went out and all of our neighbors have regained power except us ! My meter is reading error code FU6-04

Comment: Call your electricity provider and inquire. If you want even a tiny hope of an answer here, you'd need to [edit] your question to tell us the utility provider and the make and model of the meter, preferably with a close, in focus picture of the meter face so details can be read directly from the picture.

Comment: Ask your power company.  Different companies use different meters so their error codes differ.